# Draw ring with given thickness, position, and radius. (Java2D)

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, java-2d, ellipse

I need to draw a ring, with given thickness, that looks something like this:

[image]

The center must be transparent, so that it doesn't cover previously drawn shapes.  (or other rings)  I've tried something like this:

```
//g is a Graphics2D object
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.drawOval(x,y,width,height);
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.drawOval(x+thickness,y+thickness,width-2*thickness,height-2*thickness);
```

which draws a satisfactory ring, but it covers other shapes; the interior is white, not transparent.  How can I modify/rewrite my code so that it doesn't do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create an [`Area`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) from an [`Ellipse2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) that describes the outer circle, and [`subtract`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#subtract-java.awt.geom.Area-) the ellipse that describes the inner circle. This way, you will obtain an actual [`Shape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) that can either be [drawn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw-java.awt.Shape-) or [filled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill-java.awt.Shape-) (and this will only refer to the area that is actually covered by the ring!).

The advantage is that you really have the **geometry** of the ring available. This allows you, for example, to check whether the ring shape [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#contains-double-double-) a certain point, or to fill it with a [`Paint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Paint.html) that is more than a single color:

[image: RingPaint01]

Here is an example, the relevant part is the `createRingShape` method:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class RingPaintTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        RingPaintTestPanel p = new RingPaintTestPanel();
        f.getContentPane().add(p);
        f.setSize(800,800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}


class RingPaintTestPanel extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;

        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("Text", 100, 100);
        g.drawString("Text", 300, 100);

        Shape ring = createRingShape(100, 100, 80, 20); 
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fill(ring);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.draw(ring);

        Shape otherRing = createRingShape(300, 100, 80, 20); 
        g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
            new Point(250, 40), Color.RED, 
            new Point(350, 200), Color.GREEN));
        g.fill(otherRing);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.draw(otherRing);

    }

    private static Shape createRingShape(
        double centerX, double centerY, double outerRadius, double thickness)
    {
        Ellipse2D outer = new Ellipse2D.Double(
            centerX - outerRadius, 
            centerY - outerRadius,
            outerRadius + outerRadius, 
            outerRadius + outerRadius);
        Ellipse2D inner = new Ellipse2D.Double(
            centerX - outerRadius + thickness, 
            centerY - outerRadius + thickness,
            outerRadius + outerRadius - thickness - thickness, 
            outerRadius + outerRadius - thickness - thickness);
        Area area = new Area(outer);
        area.subtract(new Area(inner));
        return area;
    }

}
```

Comment: (1+) @Marco13, adding the gradient example took the extra time :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Shape` and `Area` classes to create interesting effects:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Subtract extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int size = 100;
        int thickness = 10;
        int innerSize = size - (2 * thickness);

        Shape outer = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, size, size);
        Shape inner = new Ellipse2D.Double(thickness, thickness, innerSize, innerSize);

        Area circle = new Area( outer );
        circle.subtract( new Area(inner) );

        int x = (getSize().width - size) / 2;
        int y = (getSize().height - size) / 2;
        g2d.translate(x, y);

        g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g2d.fill(circle);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.draw(circle);

        g2d.dispose();
     }


    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Subtract");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Subtract());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Using an Area you can also add multiple Shapes together or get the intersection of multiple Shapes.

Comment: So, once more, I was too slow... :-/

Answer (score 3):

You could use `graphics.setStroke(...)` for this. This way the center will be fully transparent and therefore won't cover previously drawn shapes. In my example I had to do some additional calculations because of this method though, to make sure the displayed `x` and `y` coordinates are actually the same as the ones of the `Ring` instance:

[image]

---

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example {

    public Example() {
        ArrayList<Ring> rings = new ArrayList<Ring>();
        rings.add(new Ring(10, 10, 100, 20, Color.CYAN));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                for (Ring ring : rings) {
                    // Previously drawn
                    gg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    String str = "Hello!";
                    gg.drawString(str, ring.getX() + (ring.getWidth() - gg.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(str)) / 2,
                            ring.getY() + ring.getHeight() / 2 + gg.getFontMetrics().getAscent());

                    // The actual ring
                    ring.draw(gg);
                }

                gg.dispose();
            }
        };

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }

}

class Ring {
    private int x, y, width, height, thickness;
    private Color color;

    public Ring(int x, int y, int width, int height, int thickness, Color color) {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        setWidth(width);
        setHeight(height);
        setThickness(thickness);
        setColor(color);
    }

    public Ring(int x, int y, int radius, int thickness, Color color) {
        this(x, y, radius * 2, radius * 2, thickness, color);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D gg) {
        Stroke oldStroke = gg.getStroke();
        Color oldColor = gg.getColor();

        gg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        gg.setStroke(new BasicStroke(getThickness()));
        gg.drawOval(getX() + getThickness() / 2, getY() + getThickness() / 2, getWidth() - getThickness(),
                getHeight() - getThickness());
        gg.setColor(getColor());
        gg.setStroke(new BasicStroke(getThickness() - 2));
        gg.drawOval(getX() + getThickness() / 2, getY() + getThickness() / 2, getWidth() - getThickness(),
                getHeight() - getThickness());

        gg.setStroke(oldStroke);
        gg.setColor(oldColor);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getThickness() {
        return thickness;
    }

    public void setThickness(int thickness) {
        this.thickness = thickness;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```